# override javascript method enable

Tags: javascript

Below is the javascript code to establish communication between two objects

```
var ob = function(){
    this.partnersArray=[];
};
ob.prototype.func = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
ob.prototype.setPartner = function(obj){
    this.partnersArray.push(obj);
};
ob.prototype.comm = function(data){
    for(var i=0;i<this.partnersArray.length;i++) 
    this.partnersArray[i].func(data);
};
var o1 = new ob();
var o2 = new ob();
var o3 = new ob();
o1.setPartner(o2);
o1.setPartner(o3);
//o1,o2 and o1,o3 are partners, but o2 ,o3 are not partners
o2.setPartner(o1);
o3.setPartner(o1); 

o1.comm("hello");
```

Is it possible to override     ob.prototype.func 
for example

```
o2.func->function(data){
     var s=data+" !!!"; //do something belong to o2
     console.log(s);
};
o3.func->function(data){
     var s=data+" ???"; //do something belong to o3
     console.log(s);
};
```

I mean if o1 have more than one partner, each one has itself's .func to get message from o1 and do special things.
The sample above, if o1.comm send string "hello"

o2.func output "hello !!!"
o3.func output "hello ???"

Your comment welcome

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Could explain it better and maybe provide a more complete example? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Of course you can assign a new function to `ob.prototype.func` or `o1.func` or `o2.func`.

Comment: you could set a property for the object and pass a value on instantiation and then have a switch in `ob.prototype.func`to act on the property value

Comment: I have update the question for 1 object communicate to more than one object. I hope o2, o3 have themselves 'func' to process.

Comment: Do you want object specific function behavior?

Comment: What Felix said above: just define e.g. o2.func

Comment: Change `this.partnersArray[i].func(message);` to `this.partnersArray[i].func(data);` first.

Comment: @ N K , yes specific function works, please set your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply override them? Your example pseudo code was basically what you need to do:

```
o2.func = function(data){
     var s=data+" !!!"; //do something belong to o2
     console.log(s);
};
o3.func = function(data){
     var s=data+" ???"; //do something belong to o3
     console.log(s);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways

```
var ob = function(name){
    this.partnersArray=[];
    this.name = name;
};
ob.prototype.func = function(data){
    alert(this.name + ' : ' +data + this.behavior);
};
ob.prototype.setPartner = function(obj, behavior){
    this.partnersArray.push(obj);
    obj.func = function(data){
        alert(this.name + ' : ' +data + (behavior?behavior:''));
    };
};
ob.prototype.comm = function(data){
    for(var i=0;i<this.partnersArray.length;i++) 
    this.partnersArray[i].func(data);
};
var o1 = new ob('1');
var o2 = new ob('2');
var o3 = new ob('3');
o1.setPartner(o2, '!!!');
o1.setPartner(o3);
//o2 ,o3 are not partner
o2.setPartner(o1);
o3.setPartner(o1); 

o1.comm("hello");
```

> Or

```
var ob = function(name){
    this.partnersArray=[];
    this.name = name;
    this.behavior = '';
};
ob.prototype.func = function(data){
    alert(this.name + ' : ' +data + this.behavior);
};
ob.prototype.setPartner = function(obj, behavior){
    this.partnersArray.push(obj);
    if(behavior != null)
        obj.behavior = behavior;
};
ob.prototype.comm = function(data){
    for(var i=0;i<this.partnersArray.length;i++) 
    this.partnersArray[i].func(data);
};
var o1 = new ob('1');
var o2 = new ob('2');
var o3 = new ob('3');
o1.setPartner(o2, '!!!');
o1.setPartner(o3);
//o2 ,o3 are not partner
o2.setPartner(o1);
o3.setPartner(o1); 

o1.comm("hello");
```

Comment: I tested and found, if write : ob2.func = function(data){
    var s=data+" !!!"; //do something belong to o2
     console.log(s);
};

Comment: after partner o1.setPartner(o2, '!!!');
o1.setPartner(o3);
//o2 ,o3 are not partner
o2.setPartner(o1);
o3.setPartner(o1);  it also works